# Annotation for getting the href value of a tag

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am trying to use Xstreamalias to parse xml using annotations in java.

I have the following example xml:

```
<references xml:lang="en" type="UNKNOWN">
      <source>ABCDE</source>
      <reference href="http://www.hello.com/id/12345" xml:lang="en">12345</reference>
    </references>
```

In my java code i have created annotations as follows:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "references")
    private List<Reference> references;
```

and the reference class is as follows:

@XStreamAlias("references")
public class Reference {

```
@XStreamAlias("source")
private String source;

@XStreamAlias("reference")
private String name;

private String referenceLink;
```

}

For the given xml the field source will get the value as ABCDE and the field name will get the value 12345.

Now i want to get the href link inside the reference tag using annotations and assign it the referenceLink variable. what will be the annotation for href value?

Comment: seems like you're looking for `ToAttributedValueConverter`..

Comment: @nullpointer what would be the annotation, using that ToAttributedValueConverter

Comment: Not very updated with XStream but probably `@XStreamAsAttribute` with `autoDetectAnnotations` set as `true`